# Fragment onCreate called multiple times when reload the Fragment

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, android-listfragment

Below is my code:

```
public class MyListFragmentActivity extends FragmentActivity{

@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    System.out.println("DEBUG : MLFA onCreate");
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(fragmentID, new MyListFragment())
            .replace(detailFragmentID, new MyDetailFragment()).commit();
        }
    }



     @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            Fragment prevFrag = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(detailFragmentID);
    if (prevFrag != null) {
        fragmentTransaction.remove(prevFrag);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(detailFragmentID, new MyDetailFragment()).commitAllowingStateLoss();
    } else {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(detailFragmentID, new MyDetailFragment()).commitAllowingStateLoss();
    }
}
```

**MyListFragment**

```
public class MyListFragment extends Fragment{

//When we click on each item in list view call detail fragment to relad its layout
OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener = new OnItemClickListener() {

/** Getting the fragmenttransaction object, which can be used to add, remove or replace a fragment */
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        /** Getting the existing detailed fragment object, if it already exists.
        *  The fragment object is retrieved by its tag name
        * */
        Fragment prevFrag = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(detailFragmentID);

        /** Remove the existing detailed fragment object if it exists */
        if (prevFrag != null) {
            fragmentTransaction.remove(prevFrag);
           MyDetailFragment mydetailFragment = new MyDetailFragment();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(detailFragmentID, mydetailFragment);
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.show(getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(detailFragmentID));
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
}
```

**MyDetailFragment**

```
public class MyDetailFragment extends Fragment{

onCreate() // on create being called multiple times ? why ?????????????

onCreateView()

}
```

When i click on my list item MyDetailFragment onCreate() is called only once, but when i tilt the device to portrait or landscape then MyDetailFragment onCreate() is called multiple times ?

Why so? What am i doing wrong here and how to fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

Every time you change the orientation, it is as good as restarting the app. You need to handle changes appropriately like releasing the resources, acquiring them again, stopping any work you were doing and resuming them and so on.

You aren't doing anything wrong.

Comment: how to solve in my case ? its just calling onCreate method of MyDetailFragment

Comment: Have a look at the life cycle and make changes as per your need: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#Lifecycle =)

Comment: I am doing exactly as how they have shown in the lifecycle ?  but still why the oncreate is getting called again and again ?

Comment: are you adding and removing fragments ?

Comment: Is it ready-bake code ? You are replacing the fragments, I guess, thats whats causing it `fragmentTransaction.replace(detailFragmentID, mydetailFragment);`

Comment: So you mean i have to do something apart from replacing ? right ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46312/discussion-between-goofy-and-little-child)

Comment: @Goofy have you fix this issue?